# Вылезает ошибка _tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance ""

Tags: python, tkinter

Программа должна принимать 4 координаты и рисовать по ним фигуру, которую выбрал пользователь. Но при запуске вылезает ошибка 
"_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root)


def new_window():   # создает окно со всеми нужными кнопка и полями для ввода
    win = Toplevel()

    e1x = Entry(win)
    e1x.pack()
    e1x = e1x.get() # для ввода координат начала отрезка
    e1y = Entry(win)
    e1y.pack()
    e1y = e1y.get()

    e2x = Entry(win)      # для ввода координат конца отрезка
    e2x.pack()
    e2x = e2x.get()
    e2y = Entry(win)
    e2y.pack()
    e2y = e2y.get()

    def draw():
        c.create_line(e1x, e1y, e2x, e2y)

    draw()


b = Button(text='Нарисовать', command=new_window())
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки в коде:

1. Скобки при передаче обработчика в объект кнопки `command=new_window()` - из-за этого обработчик вызывается сразу, до нажатия на кнопку. Правильная привязка функции-обработчика нажатия:

   ```
   b = Button(text='Нарисовать', command=new_window)
   ```
2. Вы создаете текстовые поля, и сразу из них пытаетесь получить значения. Сразу после создания в текстовых полях пусто, отсюда ошибка. Координаты нужно получать не сразу, а например после нажатия на кнопку, после этого уже рисовать.
3. В текстовых полях лежат строки, а координаты концов отрезка должны быть числами.

Исправленный код:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root)
c.pack()


def new_window():   # создает окно со всеми нужными кнопка и полями для ввода
    win = Toplevel()

    # для ввода координат конца отрезка
    e1x = Entry(win)
    e1x.pack()

    e1y = Entry(win)
    e1y.pack()

    # для ввода координат начала отрезка
    e2x = Entry(win)      
    e2x.pack()

    e2y = Entry(win)
    e2y.pack()

    def draw():
        x1 = int(e1x.get())
        y1 = int(e1y.get())
        x2 = int(e2x.get())
        y2 = int(e2y.get())
        c.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    Button(win, text='Нарисовать', command=draw).pack()


Button(text='Получить координаты', command=new_window).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли элемент `IntVar()`.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root)

win = Toplevel()

s1x = IntVar()
s1y = IntVar()
s2x = IntVar()
s2y = IntVar()

e1x = Entry(win, textvariable = s1x)
e1x.pack()
e1y = Entry(win, textvariable = s1y)
e1y.pack()
e2x = Entry(win, textvariable = s2x) 
e2x.pack()
e2y = Entry(win, textvariable = s2y)
e2y.pack()

def draw():
    c.create_line(s1x.get(), s1y.get(), s2x.get(), s2y.get())

b = Button(text='Нарисовать', command=draw)

b.pack()
c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```